Como Inactivar un Registro automaticamnete
estoy buscando la manera de hacer que pase un proceso en laravel después de una determinada fecha
esta aplicación lleva un año o en lanzamiento ya, y es una aplicación de control de contratos
pero ahora se presenta el problema de que los contratos a pasar el año desde su inicio, se quedan como contratos activos, lo cual no debería pasar porque el contrato ya se venció
y necesito una forma automática de cancelación, es decir, que pase de estado "activo" a "Vencido" después de que pasa la fecha de vencimiento
pero la verdad no se que herramienta de laravel se puede utilizar
o como hacer eso

Prueba con task scheduling https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/scheduling#main-content
